# running a program in haskell with just nix installed

Tags: bash, haskell, nix

If I have `nix` installed, I can run pretty much any program, without having it "installed".

- For instance a javascript program require `node`

```js
//in file  helloworld.js
const http = require('http'); // Loads the http module
http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.write('Hello, World!\n');
    response.end();
}).listen(1337);
```

and I can directly run it with

```sh
$(nix-build -E "with import <nixpkgs> { };nodejs")/bin/node helloworld.js
```

- For simple haskell, I can likewise both summon a haskell environment, and have it run directly with a bash script :

```hs
#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i runghc -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages(p: with p; [type-level-sets])"
#! nix-shell -I nixpkgs=channel:nixos-21.11

-- courtesy jyrimatti https://gist.github.com/jyrimatti/bd139e91ed257d37bc57c08ac505fc3f

{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Main where

import Data.Type.Set (Set(..), Proxy(..))

class Get a s where
 get :: Set s -> a

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Get a (a ': s) where
           get (Ext a _) = a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Get a s => Get a (b ': s) where
          get (Ext _ xs) = get xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
let lst = Ext "hello" $ Ext 10 $ Empty
putStrLn $ show $ get @String lst
```

However, say my program is more complicated, like the webserver example, and I want to target a particular package set. now all my dependencies are picked from that vetted set of packages which are known to be compatible with each others.

With `stack` **installed**, this is easy :

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-18.21 script

-- this script makes use of the http-client library, which is in stackage
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import Network.HTTP.Simple

-- An equivalent pure haskell file can also be run as
-- stack runghc --package http-conduit -- http.hs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  response <- httpLBS "http://httpbin.org/get"

  putStrLn $
    "The status code was: "
      ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)
  print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
  L8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody response
```

Is there an equivalent for `nix` which would make it simple to (reliably !) launch some haskell program, along with its dependencies, without anything special installed apart from `nix` ?

I imagine something like  :

```hs
#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i runghc -p "stackage.lts-18.21"
#! nix-shell -I nixpkgs=channel:nixos-21.11

-- this script makes use of the http-client library, which is in stackage
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import Network.HTTP.Simple

-- An equivalent pure haskell file can also be run as
-- stack runghc --package http-conduit -- http.hs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  response <- httpLBS "http://httpbin.org/get"

  putStrLn $
    "The status code was: "
      ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)
  print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
  L8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody response
```

Comment: Do you still want to use Stackage to install the dependencies, or do you want to get them from `nixpkgs`? If the latter, you can install them (I believe) using `-p 'haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (p: [p.http-conduit])'` instead of `-p "stackage.lts-18.21"`.

Comment: I would like to get the packages which are known to work together (aka, some version of stackage) from nix, for reproducibility etc. If I just point at Nixpkgs, I have no guarantee what they are. maybe they are just head version. or not even.

Comment: You want to pin your version of nixpkgs to a version of stackage that works for you.